# After mounting container as drive in Truecrypt , Windows says drive is not formatted

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, encryption, mount, truecrypt

I created a container using truecrypt long time back , and I used to mount it whenever I needed  , until one day I decided to format my laptop. So I took backup of the file container to a USB drive. Reinstalled Windows 7 ultimate.

Now I installed truecrypt and copied my file container from USB , mounted it by giving the password ( I am sure password is correct) because the container got mounted as drive X. The drive was formed and when I tried to open it , windows says "The disk needs to be formatted" !

Did I lose my important data just because I encrypted it ? How do I make windows open that mounted drive ?

see the attached image.

[image]

[image]

[image: Volume properties]

Comment: Seems like it should work. Try mount after reboot.  Try a mount on a different computer, maybe even *nix.  It's conceivable the very last encrypted write to the container corrupted the file system (probably in memory corruption before encryption).  If so, an earlier backup of the container might be the only recourse.

Comment: I tried on different computers , I tried on ubuntu,but all it shows is a lost+found folder , I have 3 backup of the same container which was taken at different months.It all shows the same problem.Now I regret using this software and trusting that my data was safe !

Comment: Others are also facing the same problem like mine http://superuser.com/questions/464115/windows-8-truecrypt-drive-mounts-but-windows-cannot-read-its-content

Comment: Q. 464115 is about disk/partition encryption, which faces things container encryption doesn't.  When did you last successfully access the contents of the container?  Were your backups made while the container was dismounted?  Had you ever tried to mount from a backup copy (to verify)?  What mount options are you using?  Tried "Use backup header embedded in volume if available"? What does Volume Properties show?

Comment: I have 3 backups , all show the same problem. I have edited the question and added screenshot of the volume properties.

Comment: @mgkrebbs When I used "Use backup header embedded in volume if available"? it asked password and when I gave password it says "incorrect password" , but It mounts the volume if I give the same password.I remember giving only 1 password while I was encrypting. So the volume header password is different ?

Comment: I haven't used truecrypt too much and don't know about backup headers.  Another feature is hidden volumes, which I haven't used either, but the docs show it could be relevant.  If you configured a hidden volume (initially), then there would be _two_ passwords which would work; one would mount the normal volume of the container, and the other would mount the hidden volume within that volume.  If you configured it that way, you should know both passwords and be able to mount either.  If the outer one was mounted and written to, it could wipe out the OS headers of the other.

Comment: I want this to be recovered somehow.Something tells me it can be done.Starting a bounty.

Comment: Have you tried using the exact same version of TrueCrypt to open the archives that you used to create them in the first place? I don't know how long back ago "a long while ago" is, but I reckon if there's any change in how TrueCrypt encrypts its drives, then there may be some incompatibility. I have no prior experience with TrueCrypt, so I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Try mounting the file from the USB drive.  As in do not copy it to the desktop.

Comment: Have you by any chance copied the container file while its volume was mounted? This is a known way to corrupt the volume. Windows should normally prevent you from copying a mounted volume.

Comment: @harrymc no , have not copied the container file like that.I have 4 backups of the same container taken at different backup times.All shows the same problem as above !

Comment: @RyanE Will try that and let you know.

Comment: TrueCrypt says X: is on `E:\XCRYPT...` while Volume Properties says it is on `C:\Users\34651\Desktop\Movies\x00...`. I guess this was its old placement. Find out the entire name, copy the container back to exactly the same place and try again.

Comment: @harrymc its a different screenshot , taken later on of the same container,just to get its volume properties to show that it has an embedded backup header.

Comment: @Tito Cheriachan, when you find an answer that works, please come back and say that, adding an answer section of your own if needed.

Comment: @mgkrebbs will do.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the file was somehow corrupted, use a disk/file recovery software on the X:\ drive and see if any of your files are recoverable.

You may also have better luck posting in the TC forums.